# ¿Token mismatch al insertar dos columnas en otra tabla de mysql?

Tags: mysql

Tengo un código que selecciona dos columnas en una base de datos:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (`owner_account`), `grouped_country`
FROM `genuine_k_value`;
```

Lo que tengo que hacer es insertar dados valores en otra tabla. He intentado hacer lo siguiente:

```
INSERT INTO `genuine_agents` ( `agent_email`, `agent_country` )
SELECT DISTINCT (`owner_account`), `grouped_country`
FROM `genuine_k_value`;
```

Pero me da:

> Error: Token mismatch

Yo sé que el query tiene que ser de forma:

```
INSERT INTO tabla (´columna1´, ´columna2´)
VALUES ('valor 1', 'valor 2');
```

Pero no logro aplicarlo a mi caso.

Comment: ese error te lo tira phpmyadmin? Y lo tira solamente en el insert pero no en el select que mostrarse previamente?

Comment: Podría ser problemas con la caché, has probado reiniciar el servidor?

Comment: @amenadiel si, me lo tira phpmyadmin en el insert, pero no en el select.

Comment: @Jemonge me has resuelto el problema !!!!! He reiniciado el servidor localhost de Wamp y funcionó a la primera !

Comment: @Lukas que bien que te funcionara. He agregado la respuesta para cerrar la pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este error suele aparecer cuando hay problemas con la memoria caché del servidor.

Una solución es reiniciar el servidor para que se limpie esta memoria y se cargue de nuevo la configuración.

Comment: Muchas gracias !